# Reprojecting trouble: shapes saved in one EPSG load as another EPSG in QGIS and are 200m off?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, arcmap, epsg, affine-transformation

I'm in a mixed working environment with some ESRI licenses and several people working with QGIS. For a project, we created data and received data in EPSG 31468 ([Gauß-Krüger Zone 4](https://epsg.io/31468)). We now need to move to ETRS 1989 UTM 33N, seven digits.

I think [EPSG 5650](https://epsg.io/5650) is the one we need (ESRI users are told to use the apparently ESRI-specific WKID 102359).

I chose to use batch reprojecting the existing polygons, lines and points using ArcMap Batch Project, and produced output in EPSG 5650.

If I now create a QGIS 3.2.1-Bonn project with this EPSG, and load a created shapefile, it gets loaded as [EPSG 5653](https://epsg.io/5653).

From the linked description, I can see that only the following lines are different in EPSG 5650:

```
AXIS["Easting",EAST],
AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","5650"]]
```

I am no geographer, but I think the Easting/Northing definition is obsolete.
But why is it ignored? This seems to happen also with other projections.

The second part of my question is more severe:
comparing the GK4 data with, e.g., Google aerials shows they are correct. After reprojecting them, they are about 200m off. I suspect I need a transformation, but I don't know how I can do this. I can't choose one when reprojecting, neither in batch nor single mode.

Comment: Difference between EPSG:5650 and EPSG:5653 should not matter with QGIS, it just does not interpret the axis order and believes that codes mean the same. But have you tried to use QGIS for opening and converting the original  EPSG:31468 data?

Comment: I did, and it seems to work, on both points. 
I'm running this as batches per directory now, and wil check on the result in ArcGIS later/tomorrow. 

I whish I had the time to learn to code this in Python.

Comment: ArcGIS doesn't hard-code the transformation parameters into a coordinate reference system definition like QGIS (using proj4) does. Make sure that ArcGIS is using the same transformation that QGIS is using.

Comment: It seems likely that the second part of my question is answered by a missing NTv2 transformation. QGIS offers this out of the box, batch reprojecting in ArcMap 10.5 does not. 
@mkennedy, I don't fully get what you mean by hard-code, since .prj-files are written by both softwares - however, I'm content to get this off my plate.